# why does my all_data function keep looping?

Tags: python, pandas, function, while-loop

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')

def main_menu():
    print("Main Menu")
    print("1) Return all current sales data")
    print("2) ")
    print("3) ")
    print("4) ")
    print("5) ")
    print("x) Exit")
    return input("Enter your choice: ")

def all_data():
    return df

# main menu loop
x = main_menu()
while x in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "x"]:

  if x == "1":
    all_sales = all_data()
    print(all_sales)
```

When I input "1" the all_data function keeps printing my dataframe in a loop without stopping. How do I fix it?

Comment: What is your intention behind this statement `while x in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "x"]`. Because if the input is in the list, then it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give input "1" for at `x = main_menu()` the program will go to the `while` loop and check the condition `if x == "1":`, then it will execute the code after `if`, `while` loop keep looping without any stopping condition, if you what to go out, you have to update value for `x`. Example:

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')

def main_menu():
    print("Main Menu")
    print("1) Return all current sales data")
    print("2) ")
    print("3) ")
    print("4) ")
    print("5) ")
    print("x) Exit")
    return input("Enter your choice: ")

def all_data():
    return df

# main menu loop
x = main_menu()
while x in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "x"]:

  if x == "1":
    all_sales = all_data()
    print(all_sales)
    x = main_menu()
```